# making a set/map comparator with find by equivalence

Tags: c++, comparator, stdmap, stdset, equivalence

What are the requirements to ensure that type equivalence can be used in the find function of a sorted container? Specifically how does mixed type comparison work.

### Setup

Say I've got a struct, comparator, and set

```
struct Wrapper{int val;};
template<class T> struct compare {...};
template<class T> using wset=set<T,compare<T>>;
```

and a main function

```
int main() {
        wset<Wrapper> s;
        s.insert(Wrapper{1}); //direct insertion
        s.insert(Wrapper{10});
        s.insert(11); //insertion by implicit construction
        s.insert(100);
        for (int x : s)
            cout << x << ' ';
        auto it= s.find(10);//find by equivalence
        cout<<*it;
        return 0;
    }
```

I can get the code to run by adding constructors and conversion overloads to the wrapper struct, and also adding parameterized binary predicates to the compare struct. But I don't understand how its actually working.

## Equivalence Implementation

From my understanding find(a) will be implemented by searching the set for an object b that satisfies !(a<b)&&!(b<a). therefore multi type equivalence should only require defining Ta<Tb and Tb<Ta ie

```
bool operator()(Ta a, Tb b){...}
bool operator()(Tb b, Ta a){...}
```

but in practice the compiler fails to make that comparison if that's all it has to go on.

### Possible Options

Its seems like my only options are to

1. let the wrapper object be constructed by the incoming type

```
struct Wrapper{
        Wrapper(int val):val{val}{};
        int val;
    };
    template<class T>
    struct compare {
        bool operator() (T const & a, T const & b) const {return a.val < b.val;}
    };
```

which seems like it has an unnecessary object being constructed

2. to add cast operators to wrapper and the operators to compare mixed types

```
struct Wrapper
    {
        int val;
        operator int()const {return val;};
    };
    template<class T>
    struct compare {
        using is_transparent=true_type;
        bool operator() (T const & a, T const & b) const {return a.val < b.val;}
        bool operator() (T const & a, int const & b) const {return a.val < b;}
        bool operator() (int const & a, T const & b) const {return a < b.val;}
    };
```

which may allow unintentional implicit conversion in other places.

3. to add cast operators to wrapper, and an operator to compare one type at time.

```
    struct Wrapper{
        int val;
        operator int()const {return val;};
    };
    template<class T>
    struct compare {
        using is_transparent=true_type;
        bool operator() (T const & a, T const & b) const {return a.val < b.val;}
        bool operator() (int const & a, int const & b) const {return a < b;}
    };
```

which like 2 may allow unintentional implicit conversion in other places.

## Working examples

1. [using a constructor, implicit conversion, and a less than operator](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:18,endLineNumber:20,positionColumn:18,positionLineNumber:20,selectionStartColumn:18,selectionStartLineNumber:20,startColumn:18,startLineNumber:20),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cset%3E%0Ausing+namespace+std%3B%0Astruct+Wrapper%7B%0A++++Wrapper(int+val):val%7Bval%7D%7B%7D%3B%0A++++int+val%3B%0A++++operator+int()const+%7Breturn+val%3B%7D%3B%0A%7D%3B%0Atemplate%3Cclass+T%3E%0Astruct+compare+%7B%0A++++bool+operator()+(T+const+%26+a,+T+const+%26+b)+const+%7Breturn+a.val+%3C+b.val%3B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0Atemplate%3Cclass+T%3E%0Ausing+wset%3Dset%3CT,compare%3CT%3E%3E%3B%0A++++%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++wset%3CWrapper%3E+s%3B%0A++++s.insert(Wrapper%7B1%7D)%3B%0A++++s.insert(Wrapper%7B10%7D)%3B%0A++++s.insert(11)%3B%0A++++s.insert(100)%3B%0A++++for+(int+x+:+s)%0A++++++++cout+%3C%3C+x+%3C%3C+!%27+!%27%3B%0A++++auto+it%3D+s.find(10)%3B%0A++++cout%3C%3C*it%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50.13553186476935,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:clang_trunk,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B2a%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.86446813523066,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) to handle multiple types on insert and in find

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <set>
    using namespace std;
    struct Wrapper{
        Wrapper(int val):val{val}{};
        int val;
        operator int()const {return val;};
    };
    template<class T>
    struct compare {
        bool operator() (T const & a, T const & b) const {return a.val < b.val;}
    };
    template<class T>
    using wset=set<T,compare<T>>;
     
    int main() {
        wset<Wrapper> s;
        s.insert(Wrapper{1});
        s.insert(Wrapper{10});
        s.insert(11);
        s.insert(100);
        for (int x : s)
            cout << x << ' ';
        auto it= s.find(10);
        cout<<*it;
        return 0;
    }
```

this works but it feels like its probably constructing a wrapper in order to do the find

2. [using implicit conversion, parameterizing the comparator operators, and making the comparator transparent](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGISQDMpK4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQgAGykAA6oCoRODB7evv5BaRmOAmER0SxxCcl2mA5ZQgRMxAQ5Pn6Btpj2xQwNTQSlUbHxSbaNza15HQrjA%2BFDFSOJAJS2qF7EyOwcANR7O%2BYB4cjeWAcBbk4zxJisJgHYJhoAgvsHZkcMJ15n925KBHujxeby8GSMO2YbAUKSYWx2M3Q9ysIP21y8Dh2AHViEwUil4iYAOwo15vfbhAg7ABuYmRTzJ5J2qAJuKIxB2lIgyzQDBmBxJNwIGwYNLpASsRIAIvTUXtiTKJQy3gRMCwUgZVX8TkwFAodgAVIHKtEEYgYqlodVNTAC0lMvZg8LATkKAD6ZsMMJtgnuUrNXkwHoAngTZYzyTFUJ5maymOzuTsIAadrz%2BeZEjsmKRDamBOmzJmYss83yqcSLEKRVmAHS02jnNw7GJ18WSmVyyPRhss%2BLxkiJ5OlguZ7OcwTD8uF5sltPlwWYYXEUVMVsNv7N%2BnSk1MqMx3tsgcliCUyfvUc5lNz88zs8VqvLrON5trrcdiNvHcCxX2/aq9Wapg2oGHqhrGp2ToQgA7gCfqwRcBqkFasI3H8RoPMaSqdgcnaniwTDhImFZfm8MGLn8OJ4qyQIIuGDoIjW4RKM0ECUfihIklwCrLHRDoKIxfLxAQrG4uxxAVlwGjcbxTL8UxQkiVRHEWFwXHSjxWEfmiAnMcJbHUZxGhSepMnkvwHInhOqg7CACI8dhDpoF45YXBu1l/BuYC7F5plvEwzmoJygIBFKDE0Aw6AQJJGm/kyTnBW4fwAFSEL5%2BwPqKUmaZ%2B0ocKstCcAArLwfgcFopCoJwiWWNYCLrJstqHDwpAEJoeWrAA1iAhUaDWXABIVhUBFwAAciSSESiQAJwDfonCSCVbUVZwvAKCAGgtW1qxwLASCYKotQBWQFAQE0wAKMohhdEICCoFBpXNchdDxlkl0RLQN13aV5VPfQCQ6kYHrmgwHVIag6p0PEADyzmffdS37bUzzEOdK3BAdyANPgpW8PwggiGI7BSDIgiKCo6hlToegGEYKDWNY%2Bh4DEa2QKsLI9GtHAALSIn6pg1ZYZhMKt9VbHoiLhG9123fD3C8GamDbM1UGiZwPD5UVi2U8tHDYBjR07KoY1c%2BNqY0y6EABiDx7VVYlg5rghAkO8w3LPLW2df4U01mNkiSIkI39YVHwaIkyQFRwC2kN9vCVRwq3rZtlPLBrHBmLwLASEZ0dLXH7vJ6s1LxBkziSEAA%3D%3D%3D) prevents unintentional construction

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <set>
    using namespace std;
    struct Wrapper{
        int val;
        operator int()const {return val;};
    };
    template<class T>
    struct compare {
        using is_transparent=true_type;
        bool operator() (T const & a, T const & b) const {return a.val < b.val;}
        bool operator() (T const & a, int const & b) const {return a.val < b;}
        bool operator() (int const & a, T const & b) const {return a < b.val;}
        
    };
    template<class T>
    using wset=set<T,compare<T>>;
     
    int main() {
        wset<Wrapper> s;
        s.insert(Wrapper{1});
        s.insert(Wrapper{10});
        s.insert(Wrapper{11});
        s.insert(Wrapper{100});
        for (int x : s)
            cout << x << ' ';
        auto it= s.find(10);
        cout<<*it;
        return 0;
    }
```

but requires that for every type combination there is a converter from WT to T and a operator for both (WT,T) and (T,WT). The converter also can't be made explicit so it exposes potential accidental conversion

3. [defining conversion between types and handle only one type per operator](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGISQDMpK4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQgAGykAA6oCoRODB7evv5BaRmOAmER0SxxCcl2mA5ZQgRMxAQ5Pn6Btpj2xQwNTQSlUbHxSbaNza15HQrjA%2BFDFSOJAJS2qF7EyOwcANR7O%2BYB4cjeWAcBbk4zxJisJgHYJhoAgvsHZkcMJ15n925KBHujxeby8GSMO2YbAUKSYWx2M3Q9ysIP21y8Dh2AHViEwUil4iYAOwo15vfbhAg7ABuYmRTzJ5J2qAJuKIxB2lIgyzQDBmBxJNwIGwYNLpASsRIAIvTUXtiTKJQy3gRMCwUgZVX8TkwFAodgAVIHKtEEYgYqlodVNTAC0lMvZg8LATkKAD6ZsMMJtgnuUrNXkwHoAngTZYzyTFUJ5maymOzuTsIAadrz%2BeZEjsmKRDamBOmzJmYss83yqcSLEKRVmAHS02jnNw7GJ18WSmVyyPRhss%2BLxkiJiCU0sFzPZzmCEflwvNktp8uCzDC4iipiN5v06Um%2BVbpWd1XqzWYbUGPWG42dp0QgDuAL9d4uBtIVthNz%2BRoexr3EYOneHLCYcJEwrbdyVvJc/hxPFWSBBFwwdBEa3CJRmggKD8UJEkuAVZZ4IdBQkL5eICDQ3EMOICsuA0HC8KZAjkOI0joMwiwuGw6VcO/BD6KI1D0JgrCNGojjaPJfgOSHSdVB2EAEVwzsELQLxywuP4dmkv41LAXZtNEt4mGU1BOUBAIpUQmgGHQCAqM4%2B0HSUky3D%2BAAqQg9P2KsVx2aiuP2BUOFWWhOAAVl4PwOC0UhUE4JzLGsBF1k2W1Dh4UgCE0ALVgAaxAYKNBrLgAmC4KAi4AAORJJCJRIAE4iv0ThJDCjKos4XgFBADQ0oy1Y4FgJBMFUWpDLICgICaYAFGUQwuiEBBUGvcLUpfOh4yyaaIloOaFvCyKVvoBIdSMD1zQYLLn1QdU6HiAB5ZTtsWlrBtqZ5iEmtrgiG5AGnwcLeH4QQRDEdgpBkQRFBUdQIp0PQDCMFBrGsfQ8BiDrIFWFkeg6jgAFpET9Uw4ssMwmHaxKtj0RFwg22b5se7heDNTBtlS68yM4HhApC5rodajhsC%2Bkb1IqnHKtTOGXQgAMzpLCBYqsSwc1wQgSHeUrlkZnrsv8GqawqyRJESMrCuCj4NESZIgo4JrSF23hoo4drOu66Hli5jgzF4FgJCE22WodzXXdWal4gyZxJCAA%3D)

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <set>
    using namespace std;
    struct Wrapper{
        int val;
        operator int()const {return val;};
    };
    template<class T>
    struct compare {
        using is_transparent=true_type;
        bool operator() (T const & a, T const & b) const {return a.val < b.val;}
        bool operator() (int const & a, int const & b) const {return a < b;}
    };
    template<class T>
    using wset=set<T,compare<T>>;
     
    int main() {
        wset<Wrapper> s;
        s.insert(Wrapper{1});
        s.insert(Wrapper{10});
        s.insert(Wrapper{11});
        s.insert(Wrapper{100});
        for (int x : s)
            cout << x << ' ';
        auto it= s.find(10);
        cout<<*it;
        return 0;
    }
```

which is simpler than option 2 but still relies on implicit conversion.

Comment: *"2. to add cast operators to wrapper"*. It is only needed because *you expect* *"unintentional implicit conversion"*, [Example 2 modified](https://godbolt.org/z/1EhacT7qY).

Comment: *"for every type combination"*. You might use projection, something like `template <typename U> bool operator()(const U& lhs, const U rhs) const { Proj(lhs) < Proj(rhs); } int Proj(const T& t)  const { return t.val; } int Proj(int n) const { return n; }`

Comment: @Jarod42 I didn't even see that i was doing that in the for loop. Cool, so that means it works the way I expected it to, I was just asking it something else that was unreasonable.